# CoreData in background thread in Swift 2.0. Clean way?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have been struggling with this problem for exactly 8 days now. So I believe it's time to ask for help for the Gurus over here.

Ok, so I am trying to implement an app following Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture, so I have the ViewControllers, Models, Interactors, Repositories and Presenters all setup.

My AppDelegate does not have any traces of CoreData in it, nothing. All that is done in the MyAppCoreData class.

The repository is injected in the AppDelegate and the Interactor access the injected object to access not only CoreData stuff, but also Parse and another private API. The Parse and private API are working great.
The CoreData repository also "works". It does not throw any exception. But no data is inserted in CoreData and when I fetch, it's empty.

I believe I am having some problem with the Persistent Store Coordinator + Main Context + Private Context... but have not yet managed to find out what it is.

So let's go to the code:

**AppDelegate**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {    
    var window: UIWindow?

    let container = Container() { c in
        c.register(UserDataStore.self) { _ in ParseRepository() } 
        c.register(BabyNamesDataStore.self) { _ in BabyNameRepository.sharedInstance }
        c.register(GenericRepository.self) { r in
            GenericRepository(_userDataStore: r.resolve(UserDataStore.self)!,  _babyNameDataStore: r.resolve(BabyNamesDataStore.self)!)
        }
    }
...
```

Then, my interactors have the following init() function:

```
class MainInteractor: MainInteractorInput
{
    var output: MainInteractorOutput!
    var worker: GenericRepository?

    init() {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        worker = appDelegate.container.resolve(GenericRepository.self)
    }
```

Then, finally, my **CoreDataStore** is a singleton (before it wasn't and I could see that it was being instantiated twice for some reason by Swinject):

```
class BabyNamesCoreDataStore : BabyNamesDataStore{

    var mainManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    var privateManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext

    static let sharedInstance = BabyNamesCoreDataStore()

    init()
    {
        QL1("BabyNamesCoreDataStore init")
        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
        guard let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BabyNameMe", withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }

        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }

        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        mainManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        mainManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
        /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
        This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
        */
        let storeURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("BabyNameMe.sqlite")
        do {
            try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            QL4("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
        }

        //let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        privateManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateManagedObjectContext.parentContext = mainManagedObjectContext

    }

    deinit
    {
        do {
            try self.mainManagedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Error deinitializing main managed object context")
        }
    }


    func fetchBabyNames(completionHandler: (babyNames: [BabyNames], error: StoreError?) -> Void) {
        privateManagedObjectContext.performBlock {
            do {
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ManagedBabyNames")
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "liked == nil")
                fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
                let results = try self.privateManagedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [ManagedBabyNames]
                let result = results.map { $0.toBabyName() }
                completionHandler(babyNames: result, error: nil)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                QL4("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                completionHandler(babyNames: [], error: StoreError.CannotFetch("Cannot fetch baby names"))
            }
        }
    }
func insertBabyNames(babyNames: BabyNames, completionHandler: (error: StoreError?) -> Void) {
        privateManagedObjectContext.performBlock {
            do {
                let managedBabyNames = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ManagedBabyNames", inManagedObjectContext: self.privateManagedObjectContext) as! ManagedBabyNames
                managedBabyNames.fromBabyName(babyNames)
                try self.privateManagedObjectContext.save()
                completionHandler(error: nil)
            } catch let error as NSError  {
                QL4("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                completionHandler (error: StoreError.CannotCreate("Cannot create baby names with id \(babyNames.id)"))
            }
        }
    }
...
```

And this is pretty much it. I get no exceptions but it is simply not working. 
Could anyone please help this desperate man ? :)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am following Raymund's Clean Store idea to implement my own, found here: https://github.com/Clean-Swift/CleanStore

I found out that the function that receives the response from the Presenter, inside the View Controller is NOT in the main thread. So I had to add this:

```
func displaySomething(viewModel: LoginViewModel) {
        if viewModel.loginStatus {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.prepareSlideOutVC()
            //When user is not logged in, the SlideOut Menu is not loaded. So when he logs in, we must load it.
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.router.navigateToMainScene()
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

adding the dispatch_async sorted out the problem in a few cases, but not all of them... still trying to figure out.
So, basically, after I login and receive the response from the Presenter, I activate the segue to go to MainVC but that was in a different thread.
Still trying to work this out.

Comment: Can you better define "not working"? How do you know this core data stack was instantiated? Did you insert an object (how do you know)? Do you find inserted objects when fetching without a predicate restricting the result set?

Comment: @Jonah The init() method from the CoreData class was invoked and the managedContext and privateContext were instantiated. I looked the memory address for both objects was the very same throughout all my test.
I also had a breakpoint in the fetch() method and insert() method. Everything went fine there - as in, the execution flow did not get inside the catch block....

Comment: Great, so what's not working? It sounds like maybe the problem is your predicate but you'll have to test to find out. Does your fetch request return results without a predicate? Can you look up your inserted object using its managed object id (see `existingObjectWithID:`)? How else might you test your app to learn more about what isn't working?

Comment: @Jonah No results at all without and without a predicate. But I just found an extremely odd behaviour: when I start the App and it does the fetch() in the coredata, no results. Then, I navigate to a different screen. And then when I come back to previous screen... THERE! The data is there.... I am essentially doing something very wrong...

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into both when this fetch method is called relative to the insert method and how/when you update your UI to reflect the results.

Comment: @Jonah I had some progress here. It's about the way the threading is organized between ViewController,Interactor and Presenter. I am following Raymund's solution to implement this, which can be found here: https://github.com/Clean-Swift/CleanStore. I've added an update to the post.

Comment: @Jonah I am positive now that this issue has something to do the way this architecture is dealing with threading. Using the protocols and Presenters and Interactors - when starting the app the Repo is instantiated in some thread that cannot present it. Somehow, when I flow to another screen and back to the Main screen, it's like these threads are synched, or something of the sort and then the data is shown. I was able to fix one of the two flows I have by adding  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) to the call... almost there, but not quite yet.

Comment: I don't see how to provide any advice here. You seem to be debugging threading issues in multiple components which are not part of this question. There's not enough information here to even suggest if you are on the right track or not. Perhaps you can condense the problem to a small example in a new question?

Comment: @Jonah I will setup a sample project in github and see if I can replicate the issue. Then share the code here.

Comment: Why do your interactors have a hidden dependency on your UIApplicationDelegate implementation?

Comment: @quellish Do you mean the dependency injection I do in the app delegate?

Comment: @FelipeCaldas no, this: `let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate` . This creates a hidden dependency on that particular *implementation* of that object.